# What is the difference between $i=(1+r)^{m}-1$ and $i=(1+\frac{r}{m})^{m}-1$?

Tags: statistics

If I put say $P$ amount of money in my account at the beginning of the year and the yearly interest rate is $i$ (as a decimal) then at the end of the year I will have $P(1+i)$ in my account.

If I put $P$ in my account and the interest was compounded $m$ times per year at a rate $r$ which is equivalent to a yearly rate of $i$ I would have to work out $r$.

I would do: $$(1+i)=(1+r)^{m}$$
I could write this in terms of $i$ as: $$i=(1+r)^{m}-1$$

But in my booklet of formulae I see the formula: $$i=(1+\frac{r}{m})^{m}-1$$
Where did that extra $m$ come from?

I suspect these two formulae are used for slightly different problems.

What is the difference between these two formulae?

Comment: Typically, compund interested is computed using the *periodic* rate $r/m$ instead of the *annual* rate.

Comment: Can you give me an example amd13 ? I'm not fully sure what that means.

Comment: If an annual interest rate of, say, $r=3\%$ is compunded monthly, the interest rate applied each month would be $r/m=3\%/12=0.25\%$.

Comment: Ok I think I have it. Thanks amd13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Rolling comments into an answer)

Compound interest calculations generally use a *periodic* interest rate, which is the annual rate divided by the number of periods, i.e., $r/m$. For example, if an annual rate of $3.00\%$ were to be compunded monthly, the rate used for the interest computation would be $$\frac rm={3.00\%\over12}=0.25\%.$$